# Pytorch model.load call ambiguity

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, model, pytorch

Simple one:

what does this do?

```
model.load_state_dict({name : 
        weights_before[name] + (weights_after[name] - weights_before[name]) * outerstepsize 
        for name in weights_before})
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load_state_dict` loads learnable parameters into neural network from dictionary.

Each layer has it's respective name and parameters. In this case you go over two dictionaries (`weights_before` and `weights_after`), `weights_after` are always used, but additionally the difference between parameter values are added multiplied by `outerstepsize`.

You can check out more in [PyTorch docs](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#what-is-a-state-dict).